# Create new eloquent instance with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

How do I create a new instance of an eloquent model with relationships.

This is what I am trying:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'Test Name';
$user->friends()->attach(1);
$user->save();
```

But I get

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to attach friend after `save` since the `attach()` method needs an `ID` to exist on the parent model. ID's aren't (usually) generated until model is saved (when a primary key or other identifier for that model is created in the database) :

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'Test Name';
$user->save();

$user->friends()->attach(1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, the attach method needs an ID to exist on the parent model. ID's aren't (usually) generated until model is saved (when a primary key or other identifier for that model is created in the database)

Comment: Thanks @fideloper for your intervention/explication, can i improve my answer with your comment?