# Laravel add relation objects to new eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wanna use a form partial for a new and for an existing object.

I found similar questions:

- [Create new eloquent instance with relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34404661/create-new-eloquent-instance-with-relationships)
- [Laravel getting builder instead of relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443115/laravel-getting-builder-instead-of-relation)

but I can't and don't wanna save the parent object.

I came from the rails view with active record. I can do the following:

Let's say I have a category which includes many products:

```
category = Category.new
category.products << Product.new
```

Now I can iterate through the products like

```
category.products.each do ...
```

Now I want the same in laravel with an eloquent model

```
$category = new Category();
$category->products()->....
```

`add` does not exist for the Builder. 
`save` needs a stored category
`attach` needs the same

is there a way to get my idea working?
My goal is to use the same form partial for edit and creating a model with defined relations.

Comment: so you want to save multiple products with the same category id?

Comment: @madalinivascu yes. but the category id does not exist currently in the database. it's a new category which includes some new products

Comment: so first create the category then create the new products

Comment: @madalinivascu i can't. it's possible thats the category is not valid. and also it could be there is a product in the collection which is not valid

Comment: then store the products in a temporary category then create the valid category, after that you update /remove the products

Comment: when do you validate if the category is valid, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from Ken, does not fit for my special situation. So i have to  create a service object which takes care of all the dependent cases. This service object stores the parent (my category) and stores the children (my products for each category) for each parent. When all data are valid, it will be persist into the database. If not, so save() returns false and i get the exception message and the validation errors.

So my service object contains the following:

```
namespace App\Services;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class FormObject
{
    protected $children = [];
    protected $parent, $validator;
    protected $errorMessages = [];


    public function save(){
        if(!$this->isValid()){
            return false;
        }
        try{
            DB::beginTransaction();

            // save parent and all relations....

            DB::commit();

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            DB::rollBack();
            $this->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    public function isValid(){
        return $this->getValidator()->passes();
    }

    public function add($identifier, array $collection){
        $this->children[$identifier] = $collection;
    }

    public function addErrorMessage($message){
        array_push($this->errorMessages, $message);
    }

    public function setParent(Model $parent){
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function setValidator(Validator $validator){
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function get($identifier){
        return $this->children[$identifier];
    }

    public function getErrorMessages(){
        return $this->errorMessages;
    }

    public function getParent(){
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function getValidator(){
        return $this->validator;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create many productions using `$category->products()->createMany([])` [Create Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

After you have a `Category` with many `Product` you can loop over them using

```
for ($category->products as $product) {
   // do something
}
```

or

```
$category->products->each(function ($product) {
    // do something
});
```

note the lack of `()` after products this will return a `Collection`

Comment: does it also works for a new category which is not stored in the database? i want to validate and create a new category with some new products

Comment: thats a good idea but did not fit to my problem. for createMany() i need an existing Category. but this Category does not exist currently